# UIImageView appearing very small in UICollectionViewCell though image is large

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Using auto layout, I have created `UICollectionView` and added an `UIImageView` inside it to show various category images. But when I run the app, though the cell is taking appropriate area on screen but `UIImageView` contained inside it is appearing very small. Any suggestion how to fix this? I am using Swift.

Using auto-layout's Pin option, I have pinned `UIImageView` to all edges of `UICollectionViewCell`.

In Xcode storyboard it looks like this:
[image: Cell Size is 150 x 150]

After running app, it is looking like this:
[image: App view in simulator]

I want `UIImageView` to cover all green space of cell to show image. I am using following code to populate `UICollectionView`

```
@IBOutlet weak var categoryCollectionView: UICollectionView!

let categoryImages = [UIImage(named: "cake"), UIImage(named: "flowers"), UIImage(named: "chocolate"), UIImage(named: "greetings"), UIImage(named: "combobox"), UIImage(named: "handicraft"), UIImage(named: "mug"), UIImage(named: "soft_toy")]

let categoryNames = ["Cakes", "Flowers", "Chocolates", "Greetings", "Combos", "Handicraft", "Mugs", "Soft Toys"]


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.categoryNames.count;
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = categoryCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HomeCategoriesCollectionViewCell


    cell.categoryImageView?.image = self.categoryImages[indexPath.row]

    cell.categoryNameLabel?.text = self.categoryNames[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are adding constraints in Any/Any size class. Are there any constraint errors in the debug log? You could try setting the background color of the UIImageView to see what size it is relative to the image so you know if its the image constraints or the image rendering that is wrong.

Comment: i have checked by applying background to UIImageView but it is also of same size as of Image inside it. No there are no error in debug log. I have added constraints using `Pin` option in autolayout to UIImageView

Comment: I don't know swift,But just try setting the frame of the imageview in cellForItemAtIndexPath method datasource method.(cell.imageView.frame=CGRectMake(0,0,cell.frame.size.width,cell.frame.size.height);as we do in objective-c) I think it will work.

Comment: Are you implementing `- collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:
` to set the size for each cell. The default value is 50x50 which looks like what you are seeing? You could also try calling `[cell layoutIfNeeded]` and see what happens after you set the image and text.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel I have set the size of cell from attributes pane to be 150. And the green box that you are seeing is the area of cell. I have applied background colour to it as green. Issue is that UIImageView is not taking complete size of cell

Comment: It could be your contentView has the wrong size. I saw this in other answers: In your cell creation metod try setting `cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds;` and `cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;`

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel `cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds;` did the job, thanks. But I am not able to write this code `cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;` as it is giving me error as **consecutive statements in a line must be separated by ;**

Comment: @Abhi Ah, that is because I posted Objective C 8^). Have added as an answer with swift code for the line you are having an issue with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like the `contentView` is not filling the cell width/height your code is returning. You could try setting the `contentView` frame to match the bounds of the cell as follows once you have created you cell in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds
cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin | 
                         UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | 
                         UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin |
                         UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin |
                         UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | 
                         UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin
```

or Swift 2

```
cell.contentView.frame = cell.bounds
cell.contentView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleLeftMargin,
                          .FlexibleWidth,
                          .FlexibleRightMargin,
                          .FlexibleTopMargin,
                          .FlexibleHeight,
                          .FlexibleBottomMargin]
```

Comment: With this code I am getting error as `Binary Operator '|' cannot be applied to two UIViewAutoresizing operand`

Comment: @Abhi Updated as it is different on swift 2. Also had a typo and was setting the frame rather than autoresizing mask.

Comment: Just a note: I got this to work without setting 'autoresizingMask'. It might be because I'm using equal widths,heights constraints and center horizontally and vertically .